# Embedded document without Array?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I understand how to [embed documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) in Mongoose, and they seem fairly straightforward if storing as arrays, for which the use case is fairly obvious:

```
var CommentSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({...});
var BlogPostSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    comments : [CommentSchema],
});
```

But, what I don't see how to do after looking over the documentation forward and backward, is how to store a single sub-document that doesn't need or want to be in an Array.

```
var UserSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({...});
var BlogPostSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    author: ??? // 'UserSchema' and UserSchema do not work here. 
});
```

Is there any way to make this work?  I don't want to just store the ObjectId, but rather, store a complete copy of the User record, but don't need or want an array.

Comment: You can do that since Version 4.2.0, see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#single-embedded

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot embed schemas in this way, with the reasoning that those child docs would be confused with full documents, see [this bug thread](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/585), where it is stated:

> the reason we haven't added this support in the past is b/c this leaves us wondering if all pre-hooks will be executed the same way for the pseudo-child document as well as it implies that we can call save() on that child.

The answer here is to share not the schema, but just the definition.

```
var userdef = { name: String };
var UserSchema = new Schema(userdef);
var BlogPostSchema = new Schema({author: userdef});
```

This would result in a nested user object, without actually nesting the Schema.

Comment: Are there any consequences of this? I mean nesting the object instead of schema?

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing information doesn't support validation bubbling. And you may need validation of UserSchema also.

Instead I recommend array length validation

```
author: {type:[UserSchema], validate: function (arr) { return arr.length == 1 }},
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

In case anyone comes across this now, as of Mongoose 4.2.0 single embedded subdocuments exist! :)

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#single-embedded