# Mongoose one-to-one relationships with embeded documents

Tags: mongoose

How can I model a One-to-One Relationship between a parent document to an Embedded Document in MongoDB?  Mongoose's populate feature will meet my needs，but it uses a reference, not the actual sub-document.

Comment: You can have a look at my project model https://github.com/cubuzoa/expressSimpleBlog/blob/master/models/Blog.js . I don't use mapping. For example I have Blog model and Comment models are embedded to this Blog model. You can use same strategy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose Sub-Document without Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635807/mongoose-sub-document-without-array)

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635807/mongoose-sub-document-without-array. And basically the answer is Mongoose doesn't support One-to-One embedded documents: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/585

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not so clear, I think this may help you.
Apart from the [schema types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), you can have your one schema referred inside another. As done in the below example:

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Comments] //Here is the Embedded schema
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a one-to-one relationship, as the OP asked for, so it does not solve the question raised by the OP.  However, it is the only way to implement schemas in a sub doc in mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose doesn't support the MongoDB feature of [Embedded documents in a one-to-one relationship to the parent document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/) with the full validation/hooks feature set.  You can store a mixed literal JSON object in a property, but you can't use the Mongoose features with that json object.

This is a limitation of Mongoose as of 4.0.  The developers assert this limitation is intentional in order to ensure the hooks feature of Mongoose performs correctly, but there is much support among users to implement a solution:  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/585