# Embedded document without array and without reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following data model:

User - Address
(one User has one Address).

For reasons of reusability I'd like to define to schema of the Address and the User in two separate files. The relations of those two "entities" should be realised as an embedded document (no array as a User has only ONE address).

Reading [Embedded document without Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635807/embedded-document-without-array) and https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/585 this is not so easy using Mongoose. According to the Stackoverflow-thread it can be done anyway like:

addressPersistenceModel.js:

```
var address = {
    street: String,
    zipCode: String,
    ...
};

module.exports = address;
```

userPersistenceModel.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var addressDefinition = require('./addressPersistenceModel');

var Address = new Schema(addressDefinition);

var UserEntityModel = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    ...
    address: Address
});
mongoose.model('User', UserEntityModel);
```

However I still get the error

```
TypeError: Undefined type at `address`
Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define you entity like that

```
var UserEntityModel = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    address: addressDefinition
});
```

You can embed the "definition" but not the schema that has been created.